# Can i run Counter Strike 1.6 on Raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: hardware, games

I really enjoy fps games and would love to play CS 1.6 but i don't know if it's possible to install on a Raspberry pi.

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: does CS 1.6 run on linux?

Comment: And even if it does, can you get an Arm version?  Best bet I would think is to get hold of a Pi 4 and try the browser version.

Comment: https://bfy.tw/PeDY